# Given a timestamp (string), how do I find the closest timestamp within a NSTextView and scroll to it. The exact timestamp may not exist

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nstextview

I have a NSTextView that displays a log (15+ mb worth of text). There will be timestamps in the log. Example snippet:

```
2018-04-22 07:54:49 <Homebound> [tests > ... Ending
2018-04-22 07:54:49 <Homebound> [tests > ... Starting
launchctl load /System/Library/
2018-04-22 07:54:50 (null)
```

I have a dropdown menu with time stamps. Timestamps are strings with this format:

```
2018-04-22 07:54:49
```

Currently I am able to select a time stamp from the drop down menu and find the timestamp within the NSTextView and scroll to where the timestamp is. Here is the code:

```
let haystack = myTextBox.string
var needle = failuresArray[selectedIndex - 1][3]
needle.removeLast(2)
// (needle would like like: 2018-04-22 07:54)
if let needleRange = haystack.range(of: needle) {
     myTextBox.scrollRangeToVisible(NSRange(needleRange, in: haystack))
}
```

Problem I am encountering is that the exact timestamp may not be in the log that is displayed in the NSTextView. How do I find the closest timestamp within the NSTextView and scroll to it?

Comment: How are you getting the text? Do you concatenate all the log elements together or are you just getting a big text file?

Comment: It is just 1 big text file, who's content is taken as a string and appended into the NSTextView. Situation is that there is a folder with a bunch of subdirectories. There are a few log/txt files that I collect and display on the app (all on separate tabs). There is a csv file with timestamps (which I append into the drop down menu) that correspond to timestamps in one of the log files. So I am able to find and scroll to timestamps within that specific log file. What I want to do is scroll to the timestamp (or closest timestamp) on every single log file.

Comment: I'm not familiar with OSX, and then I don't know if working with 15Mb is too much or not, but I'd clearly parse the whole String, with a struct/object with two items: dateObject, position and content, where position is to differentiate two logs lines with same "date" (could be also by modifying the milliseconds of it).

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to build some kind of index on your timestamps:

1. Create two variables

   - `var index: [String: [Range<String.Index>]]`
   - `var timestamps: [String]`
2. When you get the text, iterate over all the timestamps once, for each:

   - Calculate the corresponding range
   - Add an entry into `index` + append it to `timestamps`
3. When you query a timestamp, look it up in `timestamps`:

   - if it exists returns the first range
   - If not, use binary search on `timestamps` to get the closest one and query its range in `index`

You might want to do this indexing as a background task.

Answer (score 0):

I'd operate in several steps.

1. Isolate the timestamps with regular expressions.
2. Convert the timestamps into dates (using a date formatter), then the dates into TimeInterval from which you substract the time reference in your text field and take the absolute value.

The code would be:

```
    let str = <your string>
    var closestRange = NSRange(location: NSNotFound, length: 0)
    var smallestDelta : TimeInterval = TimeInterval.infinity

    let refTimeInterval = <Date from the text field>.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}", options: []) {
        for match in regex.matches(in: str, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (str as NSString).length)) {
            let range = match.range(at: 0)
            let substring = (str as NSString).substring(with: range)
            if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: substring) {
                let delta = abs(date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - refTimeInterval)
                if delta < smallestDelta {
                    closestRange = range
                    smallestDelta = delta
                }
            }
        }
    }
 print(closestRange)
```

Regular expressions are a long topic, but it's easy to find info about them, for example: https://www.raywenderlich.com/86205/nsregularexpression-swift-tutorial

Of course some form of indexing would be better, but I guess that the main part of the problem was to isolate the dates and convert them into proper dates.

Comment: "YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" is wrong `hh` means 12 hour format time without am pm is pointless. You should use 24 hour format `HH`